# Make IE 'follow' FF

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer

When developing webpages i need to test the layout and functions in both FF and IE. Anybody know of a FF addon or something else where i can make IE follow FF, meaning the if i type or click in FF IE will automatically do the same?

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by "make IE follow FF", and how an addon for FF could change the behaviour of IE.

Comment: Given that IE and FF often display things slightly differently, this probably wouldn't work particularly reliably...

Comment: What i want is to click in ie or Firefox and make the other browser do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

You should look at [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/). You define your test process with code (the clicks, the typing, etc.), and then play it back in different browsers - IE7/8, Safari, FF...  That way you can ensure that you're following the exact same process in each browser, every time.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting idea, sadly no, I don't know such a tool. The closest I know is the [IETab for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1419) at will at least give you the IE engine in the tabbed firefox environment.

Comment: Ive used IE Tab but you cant use the debug engine in IE when using that.

Answer (score 0):

You could totally do this with vb or something. I'm not a Windows guy by any means, but I know that these kinds of programs already exist to, say, automatically play 12 games of online poker at the same time.